# Angular JS Custom Filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

First, a bit of background.  Basically, I'm rendering a list of objects in a table using ng-repeat.  My filter needs to be able to take a search string, and check for each of the search terms in the objects being repeated over.  Each of the search terms need to be present (in any order) in any of the object properties for the filter to pass that object.  For instance, if an object looks like this:

```
{
    customer: 'John Smith',
    detail: 'Some details'
}
```

And my search text is `smith john` or `details john smith` or `smith john details`, it needs to be able to take those terms, in any order, and find matching objects.  The above object should match because all search terms are present.

The filter I've written is below:

```
angular.module('app').filter('assetsearch', function () {
return function (input, searchString) {

    var searchTerms = searchString === '' ? [] : searchString.replace(/  +/g, ' ').replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, '').toLowerCase().split(' ');

    var matches = _.filter(input, function (asset) {
        var textToSearch = [
            asset.customer,
            asset.details
        ];

        textToSearch = textToSearch.join(' ').replace(/  +/g, ' ').replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").toLowerCase();

        var match = true;
        _.each(searchTerms, function (term) {
            match = (textToSearch.trim().indexOf(term) > -1) && match;
        });

        return match;
    });

    return matches;
}
});
```

My template code looks pretty standard, where `$ctrl` refers to a component controller for the template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="asset in $ctrl.assets | assetsearch:$ctrl.filters.search" ng-if="!asset.loading">
```

**RESULTS**

When I search for 'John Smith', 'John' or 'Smith', it works - it just refuses to work when I reverse the string... When the string is reversed to 'Smith John' or changed to 'Joh Smith', the filter does not seem to be triggered at all (a console log at the beginning of the filter's function does not run in this case, so it seems to not be doing anything).

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the usage of underscore and methods like `replace()` to do something simpler with nested forEach loops using angularjs. The filter would be rewritten like follows:

```
app.filter('assetsearch', function() {
  return function(input, term) {
    var obj = {};
    if (typeof term !== 'undefined') {
      angular.forEach(input, function(v, i){
        var terms = term.split(" ");
        angular.forEach(terms, function(v2, i2){
          if( v.toLowerCase().indexOf(v2.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
            obj[i] = v;
          }
        });
      }); 
    } else {
      return input; 
    }
    return obj;
  };
});
```

I have also created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IeAxYHNahArbnJnL1mTB?p=preview) to show how it works in a real environment.